# How to create a .NET setup project with crystal report prerequisite?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, setup-project

I have worked on a desktop application in .net and it uses crystal report for generating report in pdf/ms word. However, I am now trying to deploying this app with visual studio setup project. Now, finding a way to bundle the crystal report assemblies in some way so that they can also install automatically on a pc where crystal report isn't installed. How can I achieve this please?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a folder called Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Crystal Reports\CRRedist\IA64 in your Programs folder. There you will find a redistributable package. Just add this file to your setup project - user defined actions - and install it.

edit: As you mentioned setupProject CustomActions only allows exe/dll files

I found another solution. Hope this ones satisfies your needs.

Add a mergeModul to your setupProject (right-click solution explorer on setupProject, add mergeModul). A folder called C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules should automatically show up. There you may find a file called CrystallReportsRedistxxx.msm. Add this to your project and it should install too.

To find the right MergeModul for your version have a look at: [BusinessObjects_CrystallReports](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp)

Adding MergeModul to setupProjects look at: [SetupMergeModul](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-merge-module.htm)

What kind of CrystalReport package to use, look at: [MS CrystalReport I](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287924%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [MS CrystalReport II](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225386%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

hth

Comment: Did you meant to add them via 'custom action' option? they only supports .exe/dlls, but i see the crystalreport file is .msi . Can you  please help by explain the step by step way to add this?

Comment: Ah, I remeber those limitations. Right now I just have a quick solution - tmt there may be some better. 1) Add a new InstallerClass to your project 2) override Install method 3) Add Process.Start("msiexec -i PATHTOREDIST\CRRedist2008_ia64.msi -quiet");   Any msi file is to be executed by the WindowsInstaller. I am doing a quick dr. google search and look for another better solution

Comment: Great, the later solution helps really :)