# How to create.Net windows application setup project having crystal reports?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have created c# windows application using Visual Studio 2010 which uses crystal reports. Now as I googled a lot to embeded crytal report package with my installer setup which is also mentioned in [Adding crystal report package to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779425/how-to-create-a-net-setup-projec-with-crystal-report-prerequisite). But I decided that I will install the crystal report package manually after installing my windows application on client machine.

Doing so gives me the error while installing

```
could not load one or more assembly
```

Then I first installed the crystal Report package and then I tried to install my application but doing so gives me the Error:

```
Stream Cannot be null
```

The log for that is shown below..

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/31/2012 @ 1:14:42 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\system32\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = mayu-PC\mayu
LOG: DisplayName = BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/system32/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\mayu\AppData\Local\Temp\CFGA0C6.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/system32/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/system32/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/system32/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/system32/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder/BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Now I don't know may be it is because of not having crystal report package with the setup or any other reason.

So what is the best way shall I include the crystal reports in my setup project as it is fine for me to install Crystal report package manually on client machine?