# Cannot load file or assembly 'crystal decisions.windows.forms,version=13.0.2000.0'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I'm working on windows application. In this I designed Report module.
I get error whenever I wanted to view report in Windows 7, Windows XP & Windows Vista, but it works in Windows 8.

Following steps I took before deploying setup

1. I installed .NET Framework 4 in Windows XP & .NET Framework 4.5 in Windows 7
2. I installed **CRforVS_13_0_2** but its through error message like

> You must already have Visual Studio 2010 installed to proceed with this installation. and
>   SAP Crystal Reports version for Visual studio 2010 installation ended prematurely because of an error.

3. Then I installed my project setup (while creating setup manually I included all crystal report assemblies), logged in and went to Report Menu, on click to open preview of Crystal Report its through error message like

> Cannot load file or assembly 'crystal decisions.windows.forms,version=13.0.2000.0,culture=neutral,Public keytoken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please guide me the how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You haven't correctly installed the required Crystal Reports Assembly, you have to install the Runtime of Crystal Reports on each client machine not the version for VS, it won't work just by copying the assmblies along with your application.

You can get the correct installers from SAP directly, maybe you will be required to create a free account.[32Bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_2.zip) [64Bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_2.zip)

Regards,

Comment: yes i did it now its working fine in all client place thank you

Comment: @echavez is there NO way that I can embed required assemblies in my Setup?

Comment: @Volatil3 yes, there are multiple ways of doing it, You may find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779425/how-to-create-a-net-setup-project-with-crystal-report-prerequisite