# Crystal report for visual studio 2012 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Using Visual Studio 2012 and Crystal Report 9

When i run the report in the client machine, showing error as "`Could not load file or assembly "CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms,Version = 13.0.2000.0 Culture = neutral PublickeyToken = 692bea5521e1304 or noe of its depcendenceis. The system cannot find the file specifified.`"

I cannot able to find `crredist2010_x86` file from the internet.

I downloaded file from SAP Site "`CRforVS_13_0_5.exe`", then i try to install on client machines it is showing error as need to install atleast `vs2010` or `vs2012` for proceeding this installation.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Duplicate question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012
Please see the question answer

Comment: Please understand my question, before posting duplicates.  I am running on client machine.

Comment: Did you download the runtime? http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 *MSI files by definitioin are for runtime distribution only.*

Comment: You need to install the VS2012 because directly we can not use it.Read the documents in answer. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: I cannot able to install vs2012 for n number of client machine

Comment: In your application installer verify minimum requirement of running crystal report into client machine and provide all requirement into your application installer at time of build report.

Comment: I got the output from this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130508/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-crystal-decisions-windows-forms-version-13-0-2000".

Answer (score 4):

Here it is!

on Jan 14, 2013 SAP released SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - 2012
**[You can download here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe)**

```
Support integration with Visual Studio 2012 and 4.5 .NET Framework runtime.
Added support for following platforms:
    OS: Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 2012
    Database: SQL Server 2012, HANA SP5
    Web Browser: Firefox 16, IE10 (limited support; more information forthcoming soon)
    Other technology: IIS 8, Flash 11
29 Customer Escalations resolved
```

This is the [presentation article.](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074)
In [this page](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) you can find actual and previous releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that I made with VS 2008 and I have installed everything but I couldn't find the dlls required. I did workaround like this Added new Report from Crystal Report and VS added the references itself.